# XmlSerializer not correct format result

Tags: c#, .net, xml

The output i want as below

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' > 
<SOAP:Body UserGUID = '{redacted}' > 
<m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' > 
<Order UserID = '1' Notes = 'Signature Requiered' CustomerID = '3' > 
 </Order >  
 </m:SaveOrder > 
 </SOAP:Body >
 </SOAP:Envelope >
```

The output xml that i am getting as my result

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:m="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body UserGUID="">
    <m:SaveOrder >
      <m:Order UserID="" Notes="" CustomerID="" />
    </m:SaveOrder>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

My XML Class code:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Order")]
public class Order {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UserID")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="CustomerID")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="SaveOrder", Namespace="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/")]
public class SaveOrder {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Order")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="m", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string M { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="SaveOrder", Namespace="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/")]
    public SaveOrder SaveOrder { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UserGUID")]
    public string UserGUID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="SOAP", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string SOAP { get; set; }
}
```

My Code where i am generating xml

```
var SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Envelope
                {
                    Body = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Body
                    {
                        UserGUID = guid,
                        SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.SaveOrder
                        {
                            Order = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Order
                            {
                                UserID = Uid,
                                Notes = "",
                                CustomerID=""                                
                            }
                        }

                     }
                    };
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("SOAP", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            ns.Add("m", "http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/");

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ECSaveOrderRequest.Envelope));

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // write the DTO to the MemoryStream
                ser.Serialize(ms, SaveOrder, ns);

                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;                       
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(ms);
                    string requestString = stream.ReadToEnd();
                    var resp = wc.UploadData(ECUrl, ms.ToArray()); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to add the Namespace to your Order class, but other than that your two XML documents are the same.

Comment: @David Browne thanks for your comments but in my XML result it is adding extra xmlns:m="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/" that is required on SaveOrder and in Order it is adding extra 'm'  that I want to fix. Can you describe me how can I do this . Or what I need to fix in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly clear the xml namespace on SaveOrder.Order or the serializer will default to SaveOrder's xml namespace.

Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ECSaveOrderRequest
{
    /*
     * <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' > 
          <SOAP:Body UserGUID = '{redacted}' > 
          <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' > 
              <Order UserID = '1' Notes = 'Signature Requiered' CustomerID = '3' > 
              </Order >  
           </m:SaveOrder > 
         </SOAP:Body >
 </SOAP:Envelope >*/

    public class Order
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UserID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "CustomerID")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    }

    public class SaveOrder
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Order", Namespace = "")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }

    }

    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SaveOrder", Namespace = "http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/")]
        public SaveOrder SaveOrder { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UserGUID")]
        public string UserGUID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAP { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Envelope
            {
                Body = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Body
                {
                    UserGUID = "{redacted}",
                    SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.SaveOrder
                    {
                        Order = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Order
                        {
                            UserID = "1",
                            Notes = "Signature Requiered",
                            CustomerID = "3"
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("SOAP", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            ns.Add("m", "http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/");

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ECSaveOrderRequest.Envelope));

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            // write the DTO to the MemoryStream
            ser.Serialize(ms, SaveOrder, ns);

            ms.Position = 0;

            var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer());
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            Console.ReadKey();



        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:m="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body UserGUID="{redacted}">
    <m:SaveOrder>
      <Order UserID="1" Notes="Signature Requiered" CustomerID="3" />
    </m:SaveOrder>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

Which is a serialization of the same XML document as

```
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' > 
      <SOAP:Body UserGUID = '{redacted}' > 
        <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' > 
          <Order UserID = '1' Notes = 'Signature Requiered' CustomerID = '3' > 
          </Order >  
        </m:SaveOrder > 
     </SOAP:Body>
   </SOAP:Envelope>
```

.

Comment: Thanks for  answer but in first node in your output result containing xmlns:m="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/"  that need to be with <m:SaveOrder . How can I set with <m:SaveOrder

Comment: No it doesn't _need_ to be on the SaveOrder node.  Where the xml namespaces are defined doesn't matter, and the serializer is free to put it on SaveOrder or any parent.  It's likely that the sample you see was generated by pasting two serialized XML documents together, as the SOAP Envelop and Body are standard, where SaveOrder is Custom.  You _could_ do the same thing, but it shouldn't be necessary.